# opencv showing black screenwhen doing screen capture

Tags: python, opencv

I am using win32api and opencv to screencapture and show it in real-time
but I am getting a black screen as an output,
In the example below the left window is the output and the right window is the one I am doing screen capture on(calculator)
[black screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsTXR.png)

I tried reinstalling everything and changing devices but nothing worked
this is the code I am using (not mine, from a tutorial)
https://github.com/learncodebygaming/opencv_tutorials/tree/2766b4a7e05f5bd4d9b49d95a9f2b6eb6c25f420/004_window_capture

Comment: Are you using macos?

Comment: I am using windows, and pycharm as IDE

Comment: windows 11 enterprise to be exact

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).